# How do I select and change text

Tags: text-editor

I downloaded a blender intro template for my youtube channel and tried to change the text to my name but I right clicking and pressing tab but I still cant select the text. I need help I am using v2.75.

Comment: With keyboard... like you may do in any text box... **or** the template you found converted it in another object type (?)

Comment: how do i convert it

Comment: you may convert it after you have set your name in it (use alt+c). But first "tab" (enter edit mode), then shift+arrows to select.

Comment: I cant select the text tho

Comment: So you may upload your blend file (http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)  or add some screen shots or add a link to where the base file can be found.

Comment: can i do that and u skype me so u can help me

Comment: ill give u the link

Comment: No Skype from here, this is not the principle. If not me, some will give you a solution here with the file you'll indicate.

Comment: If not the download link, can you post a screenshot with the text selected, and data properties panel showing?